# 3D Slicer - save content of vtkMRMLImageMetaListNode to textfile with python

Tags: python

For a python script I need the specific imageID's from a server using openIGTLink. With the Remote Module you can query a List of imageID's, patientnames, modality, etc. which is stored in a vtkMRMLImageMetaListNode.
Is there a way to get this List from the ImageMetaListNode and save it in a textfile using python?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please help folks understanding your question by posting some code that provides a Minimal example of your problem. This way you are much more likely to receive some fitting answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> cnode = slicer.vtkMRMLIGTLConnectorNode()
>>> slicer.mrmlScene.AddNode(cnode)
(vtkCommonCorePython.vtkMRMLIGTLConnectorNode)0x7fc6169b7460
>>> cnode.SetTypeClient('IGTLConnector',22222)
1
>>> cnode.Start()
1
>>> qnode = slicer.vtkMRMLIGTLQueryNode()
>>> qnode.SetQueryType(qnode.TYPE_GET)
>>> qnode.SetIGTLName('IMGMETA')
>>> metanode = cnode.PushQuery(qnode)
```

Comment: This is the code so far for initate connection and push query to get the metalist. The data from the metanode is what I try to get as a textfile.